# singular view client disconnection reason

Tags: c#, signalr

I have client and server using SignalR connection 
something weird is happening once a day
some of the clients are disconnecting and i can't see why it's happening to me

my question is how do I can log when I'm in this Hub event:

```
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        //removeing the client
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
```